# What is the best way to send custom objects to an Android service

Tags: android, android-service

Here is my scenario: My android service should act like a caching service for several applications when a network connection is broken. Each application simply post something to a website. When the network connection is broken, each application should send their message, that couldn't be sent, to my android service.
As soon as the connection is established again, the service should send the cached messages for each application.

My problem: I cannot send only the message itself as a string because my service needs more information (destination, authentication, etc). I thought about sending an object that contains all the necessary information.

My question: Is this the way to go? If so: How can i send custom objects to a service? If not: What is another way to implement it?

My example, just hypothetical:
I have the following class, that represents an Application:

```
public class Facebook{
    private Authentication auth;

    public void login(String user, String pw){
        //login
    }
    public void sendMessage (String msg){
        //send msg
    }
```

If the network connection is broken, my andorid service should take the Facebook object. After the network connection is established, my android service should send it with the sendMessage-method.

Tell me, if I have to describe something in more detail because it's not clear enough.

Comment: Basically you can NOT do that, each and every app has their OWN and PRIVATE data (FB token, auth, etc.) that you can NOT access to. Unless it's your app then you CAN do what you have described. About sending object to a Service, the simplest way is through Intent, your object may contain many of values which are primitive (String, int, etc.) so your can pack them in Intent and recreate the object by those values or you can let your object implements Serializable. Hope this I guess right and it will help.

Comment: let me make sure that i got your answer right: if my facebook class implements serializable, than its possible to send all the necessary data to the service in order to send a message (respectively make a post) after the network connection is established again?